# Send email based on Request.QueryString parameters received

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi guys I have a scenario which I would like you to see it, possible you get what I'm not getting now, I have to conditions, the first one works when parameters meet the criteria, the second one does not works (does not send the email out) even though all parameters are met:

```
       try
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            if (Request.QueryString["dot"].ToLower() == "rejected" || Request.QueryString["dep"].ToLower() == "rejected" || Request.QueryString["fdny"].ToLower() == "rejected")
            {
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("receiver@domain.org"));
                mail.From = new MailAddress("sysadmin@domain.org", "DONOTREPLY");
                mail.Subject = "The Subjectt";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = "testing testing testing";
                smtpClient.Send(mail);
            }                                                   
            else if (Request.QueryString["dot"].ToLower() == "gcl36" && (Request.QueryString["fdny"].ToLower() == "rejected" || Request.QueryString["hro"].ToLower() == "rejected"))
            {
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("receiver@domain.org"));
                mail.From = new MailAddress("sysadmin@domain.org", "DONOTREPLY");
                mail.Subject = "The Subject ";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = "testing testing testing";
                smtpClient.Send(mail);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
```

The URL looks like this: http://example.com/SPD/FileUpload.aspx?APPid=APP-016784&DocumentId=DC080497-9AFA-E511-BD4F-00155D47EC98&Userid=John Doe&SubName=Submission-1459797754588&dot=GCL36&fdny=Rejected&hro=na

As you may see in this URL the "dot" variable has the value GCL36 and "fdny" has rejected, however the second condition in the "if" never get called.

Comment: What happens when you set breakpoints and step through your code, inspecting the values as you go?

Comment: Your first `if` statement will match when `fdny=Rejected` also.

Comment: Maybe this is the main reason why I asked for help, because I can not debug the code actually and I did not want get into this neither as this is a asp net web app inside an iFrame of an entity in CRM 2016. I only want that someone maybe can see anything there that I don't see over the code...

Comment: First condition will be satisfied because dot = rejected.

Comment: It won't go in `else if` because `if` conditions is satisfied by `Request.QueryString["fdny"] == "rejected"`.

Comment: @adrianbanks if I divide this condition in two if, it does not work although, the second if never get called, if I remove the first if neither!

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya as I just told to adrianbanks, even if I use two if conditions separately without "else" it does not works though

Comment: How did you use two if conditions separately? Can you share that? We can solve issue if its with the code. We can not help you write logic. Can you tell us what should be the logical flow based on the query string parameter values?

Comment: I'd say put your if condition in your else if, and vice versa. The most explicit logic usually should come first.

Comment: I looked at the code closely again and to me it looked like problem with the code and it is throwing exception in the first `if` block itself. Please go thru my answer below for the explanation and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I found the issue with the code. With the current code and the example URL even the first if block will not be executed.

In the first if block you are also checking `Request.QueryString["dep"].ToString()`. The example URL you have posted does not have parameter `dep`. That's why if statement will throw `NullReferenceException` and it will directly go to `catch` block and return from there without performing any action.

What you need to do is make sure that making sure that QueryString parameters are not null before you use them. Also you need to make sure the specific conditions are checked first before the generic conditions.

```
try
{
    var dot = Request.QueryString["dot"]?.ToLower() ?? string.Empty;
    var dep = Request.QueryString["dep"]?.ToLower() ?? string.Empty;
    var fdny = Request.QueryString["fdny"]?.ToLower() ?? string.Empty;
    var hro = Request.QueryString["hro"]?.ToLower() ?? string.Empty;

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    //Putting if block of more specific condition check first.
    if (dot == "gcl36" && (fdny == "rejected" || hro == "rejected"))
    {
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("receiver@domain.org"));
        mail.From = new MailAddress("sysadmin@domain.org", "DONOTREPLY");
        mail.Subject = "The Subject ";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = "testing testing testing";
        smtpClient.Send(mail);
    }
    else if (dot == "rejected" || dep == "rejected" || fdny == "rejected")
    {
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("receiver@domain.org"));
        mail.From = new MailAddress("sysadmin@domain.org", "DONOTREPLY");
        mail.Subject = "The Subjectt";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = "testing testing testing";
        smtpClient.Send(mail);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return;
}
```

This should resolve you issue.

P.S. You could have identified the issue if you have handled the exception properly in catch block. Simply returning from catch block will put you in this kind of situations quite frequently.

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what was happening, I was missing the "dep" variable in the URL which either can be fixed with your example (best way) or sending that variable through the JavaScript as &dep=na  or whatever! Thank you again.